# plot climate data of different location

Tags: r, graph, temperature

I would like to compare the climate data (Temperature TMP) of two different locations in one graph. To make it more complicated, the time is overlapping but not the same. I know, I cannot really compare these data. Therefore I would like to make a graph that shows this issue in one graph.

Thanks for your help in advance.

I attached a subset of my data

```
{location   time    PAR HMD TMP DEW
DEWK    28.2.15 0:00    0   93.9    4.9 4
DEWK    28.2.15 0:15    0   93.9    4.9 4
DEWK    28.2.15 0:30    0   93.9    4.8 3.9
DEWK    28.2.15 0:45    0   94.3    4.8 3.9
DEWK    28.2.15 1:00    0   95.1    4.7 4
DEWK    28.2.15 1:15    0   95.4    4.7 4
DEWK    28.2.15 1:30    0   95.4    4.6 3.9
DEWK    28.2.15 1:45    0   95.4    4.4 3.7
DEWK    28.2.15 2:00    0   95.4    4.4 3.7
DEWK    28.2.15 2:15    0   95.4    4.4 3.7
DEWK    28.2.15 2:30    0   95.6    4.3 3.6
DEWK    28.2.15 2:45    0   96  4.3 3.7
DEWK    28.2.15 3:00    0   96.2    4.3 3.7
DEWK    28.2.15 3:15    0   96.2    4.3 3.7
DEWK    28.2.15 3:30    0   96.2    4.3 3.7
DEWK    28.2.15 3:45    0   96.2    4.4 3.8
DEWK    28.2.15 4:00    0   96.2    4.4 3.8
DEWK    28.2.15 4:15    0   96.3    4.4 3.8
DEWK    28.2.15 4:30    0   96.6    4.4 3.9
DEWK    28.2.15 4:45    0   96.9    4.3 3.8
DEWK    28.2.15 5:00    0   97.1    4.3 3.9
DEWK    28.2.15 5:15    0   97.1    4.2 3.8
DEWK    28.2.15 5:30    0   97.1    4.1 3.7
DEWK    28.2.15 5:45    0   97.1    3.9 3.5
DEWK    28.2.15 6:00    0   97  3.6 3.2
DEWK    28.2.15 6:15    0   96.3    3.1 2.5
DEWK    28.2.15 6:30    0   96.1    2.7 2.1
DEWK    28.2.15 6:45    0   95.4    2.4 1.7
DEWK    28.2.15 7:00    0   95.3    2.1 1.4
DEWK    28.2.15 7:15    0   94.1    1.8 0.9
DEWK    28.2.15 7:30    0   93.9    1.7 0.8
DEWK    28.2.15 7:45    0   93.9    1.6 0.7
DEWK    28.2.15 8:00    0   93.9    1.4 0.5
DEWK    28.2.15 8:15    10  93.5    1.3 0.3
DEWK    28.2.15 8:30    19  92.9    1.2 0.2
DEWK    28.2.15 8:45    32  92.3    1.2 0.1
DEWK    28.2.15 9:00    48  91.7    1.4 0.2
DEWK    28.2.15 9:15    72  90.7    2.1 0.7
DEWK    28.2.15 9:30    100 89.7    3.1 1.5
DEWK    28.2.15 9:45    164 86  5.6 3.4
DEWK    28.2.15 10:00   110 76  7.4 3.5
DEWK    28.2.15 10:15   223 71.8    8.6 3.8
DEWK    28.2.15 10:30   275 61.6    11.9    4.8
DEWK    28.2.15 10:45   317 51  14.8    4.8
DEWK    28.2.15 11:00   272 45.7    15.9    4.2
DEWK    28.2.15 11:15   342 46.1    16.4    4.7
DEWK    28.2.15 11:30   358 45.1    18.4    6.3
DEWK    28.2.15 11:45   189 44.3    19.2    6.7
DEWK    28.2.15 12:00   226 45.1    19.7    7.4
DEWK    28.2.15 12:15   211 48  18.8    7.6
DEWK    28.2.15 12:30   237 49  18.2    7.3
DEWK    28.2.15 12:45   241 49.7    17.6    7
DEWK    28.2.15 13:00   219 50.5    17.3    6.9
DEWK    28.2.15 13:15   147 51.9    16.7    6.8
DEWK    28.2.15 13:30   201 53.5    15.8    6.4
DEWK    28.2.15 13:45   185 54.8    15.4    6.4
DEWK    28.2.15 14:00   172 54.3    15.2    6.1
DEWK    28.2.15 14:15   218 52.5    15.4    5.8
DEWK    28.2.15 14:30   208 50.8    15.7    5.5
DEWK    28.2.15 14:45   195 49.8    15.8    5.3
DEWK    28.2.15 15:00   400 49.1    16.4    5.7
DEWK    28.2.15 15:15   391 35.7    12.1    -2.8
DEWK    28.2.15 15:30   178 43.4    8.6 -3.2
DEWK    28.2.15 15:45   157 46.3    8.3 -2.6
DEWK    28.2.15 16:00   237 51.5    9.2 -0.3
DEWK    28.2.15 16:15   138 51.7    14.4    4.6
DEWK    28.2.15 16:30   279 52.1    16.1    6.3
DEWK    28.2.15 16:45   119 51.5    16.3    6.3
DEWK    28.2.15 17:00   163 53.4    16.3    6.8
DEWK    28.2.15 17:15   95  54.5    15.7    6.6
DEWK    28.2.15 17:30   88  57.5    14.6    6.4
DEWK    28.2.15 17:45   60  60.3    13.4    5.9
DEWK    28.2.15 18:00   41  62.4    11.8    4.9
DEWK    28.2.15 18:15   25  65.5    10.5    4.4
DEWK    28.2.15 18:30   13  68.7    9.1 3.7
DEWK    28.2.15 18:45   0   72.4    7.7 3.1
DEWK    28.2.15 19:00   0   76.1    6.6 2.7
DEWK    28.2.15 19:15   0   78.6    5.8 2.4
DEWK    28.2.15 19:30   0   80.4    5   1.9
DEWK    28.2.15 19:45   0   81.3    4.3 1.4
DEWK    28.2.15 20:00   0   82.3    3.9 1.2
DEWK    28.2.15 20:15   0   83.1    3.4 0.8
DEWK    28.2.15 20:30   0   83.5    3.1 0.6
DEWK    28.2.15 20:45   0   84.1    2.7 0.3
DEWK    28.2.15 21:00   0   84.3    2.4 0
DEWK    28.2.15 21:15   0   84.3    2.1 -0.3
DEWK    28.2.15 21:30   0   84.6    1.9 -0.4
DEWK    28.2.15 21:45   0   84.8    1.6 -0.7
DEWK    28.2.15 22:00   0   85.5    1.4 -0.8
DEWK    28.2.15 22:15   0   85.7    1.3 -0.8
DEWK    28.2.15 22:30   0   86.4    1.2 -0.8
DEWK    28.2.15 22:45   0   86.8    1.1 -0.9
DEWK    28.2.15 23:00   0   86.9    0.9 -1.1
DEWK    28.2.15 23:15   0   86.9    0.7 -1.3
DEWK    28.2.15 23:30   0   86.7    0.4 -1.6
DEWK    28.2.15 23:45   0   86.6    0.3 -1.7
DEWK    1.3.15 0:00 0   86.7    0.2 -1.8
DEWK    1.3.15 0:15 0   86.9    0.1 -1.8
DEWK    1.3.15 0:30 0   86.9    -0.2    -2.1
DEWK    1.3.15 0:45 0   86.9    -0.3    -2.2
DEWK    1.3.15 1:00 0   86.9    -0.3    -2.2
DEWK    1.3.15 1:15 0   87.5    -0.3    -2.1
DEWK    1.3.15 1:30 0   87.8    -0.4    -2.2
DEWK    1.3.15 1:45 0   88  -0.3    -2.1
DEWK    1.3.15 2:00 0   88.5    -0.3    -2
DEWK    1.3.15 2:15 0   89  -0.3    -1.9
DEWK    1.3.15 2:30 0   89.4    -0.3    -1.9
DEWK    1.3.15 2:45 0   89.8    -0.3    -1.8
DEWK    1.3.15 3:00 0   90.3    -0.3    -1.7
DEWK    1.3.15 3:15 0   90.6    -0.3    -1.7
DEWK    1.3.15 3:30 0   90.6    -0.3    -1.7
DEWK    1.3.15 3:45 0   90.6    -0.3    -1.7
DEWK    1.3.15 4:00 0   90.6    -0.3    -1.7
DEWK    1.3.15 4:15 0   91.1    -0.2    -1.5
DEWK    1.3.15 4:30 0   91.4    -0.2    -1.5
DEWK    1.3.15 4:45 0   92  -0.1    -1.3
DEWK    1.3.15 5:00 0   92.3    0   -1.1
DEWK    1.3.15 5:15 0   92.3    0.1 -1
DEWK    1.3.15 5:30 0   92.3    0.1 -1
DEWK    1.3.15 5:45 0   92.3    0.2 -0.9
DEWK    1.3.15 6:00 0   92.3    0.4 -0.7
DEWK    1.3.15 6:15 0   92.7    0.5 -0.6
DEWK    1.3.15 6:30 0   93.1    0.7 -0.3
DEWK    1.3.15 6:45 0   93.1    0.8 -0.2
DEWK    1.3.15 7:00 0   93.4    0.9 -0.1
DEWK    1.3.15 7:15 0   93.8    1.1 0.2
DEWK    1.3.15 7:30 0   93.9    1.2 0.3
DEWK    1.3.15 7:45 0   93.9    1.3 0.4
DEWK    1.3.15 8:00 0   93.9    1.4 0.5
DEWK    1.3.15 8:15 0   93.9    1.6 0.7
DEWK    1.3.15 8:30 11  93.9    1.9 1
DEWK    1.3.15 8:45 15  93.9    2.1 1.2
DEWK    1.3.15 9:00 29  93.9    2.3 1.4
DEWK    1.3.15 9:15 41  93.9    2.6 1.7
DEWK    1.3.15 9:30 42  93.9    2.8 1.9
DEWK    1.3.15 9:45 62  93.9    3.1 2.2
DEWK    1.3.15 10:00    84  93.6    3.7 2.7
DEWK    1.3.15 10:15    95  92.8    4.2 3.1
DEWK    1.3.15 10:30    88  90.9    4.7 3.3
DEWK    1.3.15 10:45    104 89.7    5.1 3.5
DEWK    1.3.15 11:00    103 87.8    5.7 3.8
DEWK    1.3.15 11:15    117 86.9    6.1 4.1
DEWK    1.3.15 11:30    105 85.6    6.3 4.1
DEWK    1.3.15 11:45    82  84.8    6.3 3.9
DEWK    1.3.15 12:00    57  84.5    6.1 3.7
DEWK    1.3.15 12:15    64  85.3    5.8 3.5
DEWK    1.3.15 12:30    89  86.4    5.9 3.8
DEWK    1.3.15 12:45    79  86.4    6.2 4.1
DEWK    1.3.15 13:00    48  86.5    6.1 4
DEWK    1.3.15 13:15    50  87.1    5.9 3.9
DEWK    1.3.15 13:30    79  87.5    6.1 4.2
DEWK    1.3.15 13:45    114 87.3    6.4 4.4
DEWK    1.3.15 14:00    124 87.2    7.1 5.1
DEWK    1.3.15 14:15    107 86.6    8.1 6
DEWK    1.3.15 14:30    89  85.4    8.1 5.8
DEWK    1.3.15 14:45    154 84.5    8.6 6.1
DEWK    1.3.15 15:00    298 82.6    10.4    7.6
DEWK    1.3.15 15:15    191 77.4    12.2    8.4
DEWK    1.3.15 15:30    220 74  13.2    8.7
DEWK    1.3.15 15:45    265 69  15.3    9.7
DEWK    1.3.15 16:00    207 65  16.4    9.9
DEWK    1.3.15 16:15    205 61.3    17.4    10
DEWK    1.3.15 16:30    120 59.7    16.9    9.1
DEWK    1.3.15 16:45    54  62.9    15.4    8.4
DEWK    1.3.15 17:00    46  66.9    13.8    7.8
DEWK    1.3.15 17:15    12  70.3    12.4    7.2
DEWK    1.3.15 17:30    54  73.9    11.3    6.9
DEWK    1.3.15 17:45    65  76.2    10.7    6.7
DEWK    1.3.15 18:00    46  77.5    10.7    7
DEWK    1.3.15 18:15    16  78.5    9.9 6.4
DEWK    1.3.15 18:30    0   81.2    8.8 5.8
DEWK    1.3.15 18:45    0   83.9    8.1 5.5
DEWK    1.3.15 19:00    0   85.9    7.7 5.5
DEWK    1.3.15 19:15    0   87.1    7.3 5.3
DEWK    1.3.15 19:30    0   88  6.7 4.8
DEWK    1.3.15 19:45    0   89.1    6.1 4.4
DEWK    1.3.15 20:00    0   90.5    5.9 4.4
DEWK    1.3.15 20:15    0   92  5.7 4.5
DEWK    1.3.15 20:30    0   93.4    5.3 4.3
DEWK    1.3.15 20:45    0   93.9    5.1 4.2
DEWK    1.3.15 21:00    0   94.2    4.9 4
DEWK    1.3.15 21:15    0   94.7    4.5 3.7
DEWK    1.3.15 21:30    0   94.5    4.2 3.4
DEWK    1.3.15 21:45    0   93.9    3.8 2.9
DEWK    1.3.15 22:00    0   93.9    3.4 2.5
DEWK    1.3.15 22:15    0   93.9    3.1 2.2
DEWK    1.3.15 22:30    0   93.9    2.8 1.9
DEWK    1.3.15 22:45    0   93.9    2.7 1.8
DEWK    1.3.15 23:00    0   93.9    2.5 1.6
DEWK    1.3.15 23:15    0   93.9    2.3 1.4
DEWK    1.3.15 23:30    0   93.9    2.2 1.3
DEWK    1.3.15 23:45    0   93.9    1.9 1
DEWK    2.3.15 0:00 0   93.9    1.7 0.8
DEWK    2.3.15 0:15 0   93.9    1.6 0.7
DEWK    2.3.15 0:30 0   93.9    1.4 0.5
DEWK    2.3.15 0:45 0   93.9    1.2 0.3
DEWK    2.3.15 1:00 0   93.8    1   0.1
DEWK    2.3.15 1:15 0   93.9    1.1 0.2
DEWK    2.3.15 1:30 0   94.4    1.2 0.4
DEWK    2.3.15 1:45 0   95.4    1.3 0.6
DEWK    2.3.15 2:00 0   95.4    1.2 0.5
DEWK    2.3.15 2:15 0   95.6    1.3 0.7
DEWK    2.3.15 2:30 0   96.1    1.3 0.7
DEWK    2.3.15 2:45 0   96.2    1.2 0.6
DEWK    2.3.15 3:00 0   96.2    1.1 0.5
DEWK    2.3.15 3:15 0   96.2    1.1 0.5
DEWK    2.3.15 3:30 0   96.2    1.1 0.5
DEWK    2.3.15 3:45 0   96.2    0.9 0.3
DEWK    2.3.15 4:00 0   96.2    0.9 0.3
DEWK    2.3.15 4:15 0   96.2    0.9 0.3
DEWK    2.3.15 4:30 0   96.2    0.8 0.2
DEWK    2.3.15 4:45 0   96.2    0.8 0.2
DEWK    2.3.15 5:00 0   96.2    0.9 0.3
DEWK    2.3.15 5:15 0   96.7    1.1 0.6
DEWK    2.3.15 5:30 0   97.1    1.3 0.9
DEWK    2.3.15 5:45 0   97.1    1.4 1
DEWK    2.3.15 6:00 0   97.1    1.6 1.2
DEWK    2.3.15 6:15 0   97.2    1.8 1.4
DEWK    2.3.15 6:30 0   97.7    2.1 1.8
DEWK    2.3.15 6:45 0   98.1    2.3 2
DEWK    2.3.15 7:00 0   98.5    2.4 2.2
DEWK    2.3.15 7:15 0   98.8    2.6 2.4
DEWK    2.3.15 7:30 0   99.2    2.8 2.7
DEWK    2.3.15 7:45 0   99.5    3   2.9
DEWK    2.3.15 8:00 0   99.5    3.2 3.1
DEWK    2.3.15 8:15 0   99.5    3.4 3.3
DEWK    2.3.15 8:30 10  99.5    3.6 3.5
DEWK    2.3.15 8:45 40  99.5    3.9 3.8
DEWK    2.3.15 9:00 41  99.5    4.4 4.3
DEWK    2.3.15 9:15 63  99.5    4.7 4.6
DEWK    2.3.15 9:30 93  99.2    5.2 5.1
DEWK    2.3.15 9:45 69  98.7    5.6 5.4
DEWK    2.3.15 10:00    103 98.5    6.2 6
DEWK    2.3.15 10:15    235 96.2    7.7 7.1
DEWK    2.3.15 10:30    290 88.7    10.6    8.8
DEWK    2.3.15 10:45    438 69.3    12.9    7.5
DEWK    2.3.15 11:00    232 57.2    14.5    6.2
DEWK    2.3.15 11:15    130 58.5    13.5    5.6
DEWK    2.3.15 11:30    241 59.8    12.7    5.1
DEWK    2.3.15 11:45    198 59.7    13.1    5.5
DEWK    2.3.15 12:00    166 59.6    12.4    4.8
DEWK    2.3.15 12:15    216 60  12.6    5.1
DEWK    2.3.15 12:30    255 57.6    13.8    5.6
DEWK    2.3.15 12:45    205 54.6    14.8    5.8
DEWK    2.3.15 13:00    148 52.1    14.7    5
DEWK    2.3.15 13:15    129 54.7    13.4    4.5
DEWK    2.3.15 13:30    244 56.8    13.6    5.2
DEWK    2.3.15 13:45    221 54  15.2    6
DEWK    2.3.15 14:00    104 52.4    13.8    4.2
DEWK    2.3.15 14:15    136 56.3    12.4    4
DEWK    2.3.15 14:30    152 59.7    12.1    4.6
DEWK    2.3.15 14:45    183 60.1    11.9    4.5
DEWK    2.3.15 15:00    176 60.6    12.4    5.1
DEWK    2.3.15 15:15    98  60.2    12.3    4.9
DEWK    2.3.15 15:30    54  63.4    10.7    4.1
DEWK    2.3.15 15:45    298 65.9    11.2    5.1
DEWK    2.3.15 16:00    165 58.7    14.2    6.3
DEWK    2.3.15 16:15    211 57.6    13.9    5.7
DEWK    2.3.15 16:30    147 55.9    14.2    5.6
DEWK    2.3.15 16:45    113 57.9    13.2    5.1
DEWK    2.3.15 17:00    90  60.2    12.9    5.4
DEWK    2.3.15 17:15    19  63.7    11.8    5.2
DEWK    2.3.15 17:30    63  66.9    9.5 3.7
DEWK    2.3.15 17:45    67  69.5    8.4 3.2
DEWK    2.3.15 18:00    22  71.8    7.8 3.1
DEWK    2.3.15 18:15    32  75.3    7.3 3.3
DEWK    2.3.15 18:30    10  77.2    6.6 2.9
DEWK    2.3.15 18:45    0   80.1    5.8 2.6
DEWK    2.3.15 19:00    0   83.1    5.3 2.7
DEWK    2.3.15 19:15    0   84.6    4.8 2.4
DEWK    2.3.15 19:30    0   85.7    4.3 2.1
DEWK    2.3.15 19:45    0   86.3    3.9 1.8
DEWK    2.3.15 20:00    0   86.7    3.6 1.6
DEWK    2.3.15 20:15    0   87  3.4 1.4
DEWK    2.3.15 20:30    0   87.7    3.1 1.2
DEWK    2.3.15 20:45    0   87.8    2.9 1.1
DEWK    2.3.15 21:00    0   88  2.6 0.8
DEWK    2.3.15 21:15    0   88.2    2.4 0.6
DEWK    2.3.15 21:30    0   88.2    2.2 0.4
DEWK    2.3.15 21:45    0   88.7    2.1 0.4
DEWK    2.3.15 22:00    0   89.4    1.9 0.3
DEWK    2.3.15 22:15    0   90.1    1.9 0.4
DEWK    2.3.15 22:30    0   90.6    1.9 0.5
DEWK    2.3.15 22:45    0   91.5    1.9 0.6
DEWK    2.3.15 23:00    0   92.4    2   0.9
DEWK    2.3.15 23:15    0   93.1    2.1 1.1
DEWK    2.3.15 23:30    0   93.8    2.1 1.2
DEWK    2.3.15 23:45    0   93.9    2.2 1.3
NLAD    27.2.15 0:00    0   86.1    -11.9   -13.8
NLAD    27.2.15 0:15    0   84.2    -11.9   -14
NLAD    27.2.15 0:30    0   82.5    -11.9   -14.3
NLAD    27.2.15 0:45    0   82.3    -12 -14.4
NLAD    27.2.15 1:00    0   82.5    -12.1   -14.4
NLAD    27.2.15 1:15    0   83.1    -12.1   -14.4
NLAD    27.2.15 1:30    0   83.3    -12.2   -14.5
NLAD    27.2.15 1:45    0   82.8    -12.4   -14.7
NLAD    27.2.15 2:00    0   81.8    -12.4   -14.9
NLAD    27.2.15 2:15    0   81.8    -12.4   -14.9
NLAD    27.2.15 2:30    0   81.9    -12.6   -15
NLAD    27.2.15 2:45    0   82.3    -12.6   -15
NLAD    27.2.15 3:00    0   82.4    -12.7   -15.1
NLAD    27.2.15 3:15    0   83  -12.7   -15
NLAD    27.2.15 3:30    0   83.3    -12.7   -15
NLAD    27.2.15 3:45    0   83.4    -12.8   -15
NLAD    27.2.15 4:00    0   83.5    -12.9   -15.1
NLAD    27.2.15 4:15    0   84  -13 -15.1
NLAD    27.2.15 4:30    0   84.8    -13.1   -15.1
NLAD    27.2.15 4:45    0   84.8    -13.1   -15.1
NLAD    27.2.15 5:00    0   84.3    -13.2   -15.3
NLAD    27.2.15 5:15    0   84  -13.3   -15.4
NLAD    27.2.15 5:30    0   84  -13.4   -15.5
NLAD    27.2.15 5:45    0   83.9    -13.4   -15.6
NLAD    27.2.15 6:00    0   84  -13.6   -15.7
NLAD    27.2.15 6:15    0   84.3    -13.7   -15.8
NLAD    27.2.15 6:30    0   84.6    -13.8   -15.8
NLAD    27.2.15 6:45    0   85.1    -13.8   -15.8
NLAD    27.2.15 7:00    0   85.7    -13.9   -15.8
NLAD    27.2.15 7:15    0   85.6    -13.8   -15.7
NLAD    27.2.15 7:30    0   85.8    -13.8   -15.7
NLAD    27.2.15 7:45    0   85.6    -13.9   -15.8
NLAD    27.2.15 8:00    0   85.3    -13.8   -15.8
NLAD    27.2.15 8:15    0   84.8    -13.8   -15.9
NLAD    27.2.15 8:30    0   84.5    -13.9   -16
NLAD    27.2.15 8:45    19  83.7    -13.8   -16
NLAD    27.2.15 9:00    35  83.3    -13.7   -16
NLAD    27.2.15 9:15    54  82.8    -13.6   -15.9
NLAD    27.2.15 9:30    77  81.2    -13.4   -16
NLAD    27.2.15 9:45    129 79.3    -13.1   -15.9
NLAD    27.2.15 10:00   150 77.1    -12.4   -15.6
NLAD    27.2.15 10:15   136 74.2    -12.2   -15.8
NLAD    27.2.15 10:30   150 72.2    -12.1   -16.1
NLAD    27.2.15 10:45   213 70.6    -11.7   -16
NLAD    27.2.15 11:00   214 67.8    -11.2   -16
NLAD    27.2.15 11:15   261 65.6    -11.3   -16.5
NLAD    27.2.15 11:30   454 63.3    -10.4   -16.1
NLAD    27.2.15 11:45   545 58.4    -9.7    -16.3
NLAD    27.2.15 12:00   252 55.3    -9.8    -17.1
NLAD    27.2.15 12:15   504 54.2    -9.8    -17.4
NLAD    27.2.15 12:30   690 49  -8.7    -17.5
NLAD    27.2.15 12:45   573 48.3    -8.2    -17.3
NLAD    27.2.15 13:00   304 46.3    -8.4    -18
NLAD    27.2.15 13:15   479 49.4    -9  -17.7
NLAD    27.2.15 13:30   760 47.8    -8.4    -17.6
NLAD    27.2.15 13:45   629 45.9    -8.2    -17.9
NLAD    27.2.15 14:00   833 46  -8.8    -18.4
NLAD    27.2.15 14:15   910 43.6    -8.3    -18.6
NLAD    27.2.15 14:30   713 42.4    -8.4    -19.1
NLAD    27.2.15 14:45   788 45.1    -9.3    -19.1
NLAD    27.2.15 15:00   783 48.4    -9.2    -18.2
NLAD    27.2.15 15:15   696 48.1    -9.2    -18.2
NLAD    27.2.15 15:30   323 49.3    -9.8    -18.5
NLAD    27.2.15 15:45   294 52.2    -10.4   -18.3
NLAD    27.2.15 16:00   304 52.5    -9.8    -17.7
NLAD    27.2.15 16:15   350 47.1    -8.8    -18.1
NLAD    27.2.15 16:30   163 48.3    -9.8    -18.7
NLAD    27.2.15 16:45   158 55.1    -10.6   -17.9
NLAD    27.2.15 17:00   321 51.2    -9.4    -17.6
NLAD    27.2.15 17:15   153 50.4    -10.2   -18.6
NLAD    27.2.15 17:30   118 55.9    -11.3   -18.3
NLAD    27.2.15 17:45   113 59.6    -11.8   -18
NLAD    27.2.15 18:00   75  61.9    -12.1   -17.9
NLAD    27.2.15 18:15   58  65.6    -12.6   -17.6
NLAD    27.2.15 18:30   49  68.3    -12.9   -17.5
NLAD    27.2.15 18:45   31  70  -13.4   -17.7
NLAD    27.2.15 19:00   13  72.3    -13.9   -17.8
NLAD    27.2.15 19:15   0   75.5    -13.9   -17.3
NLAD    27.2.15 19:30   0   77.8    -13.9   -16.9
NLAD    27.2.15 19:45   0   80.3    -13.8   -16.4
NLAD    27.2.15 20:00   0   82.9    -13.7   -16
NLAD    27.2.15 20:15   0   84.5    -13.7   -15.7
NLAD    27.2.15 20:30   0   85.2    -13.7   -15.7
NLAD    27.2.15 20:45   0   85.7    -13.7   -15.6
NLAD    27.2.15 21:00   0   85.8    -13.8   -15.7
NLAD    27.2.15 21:15   0   86.1    -14.1   -15.9
NLAD    27.2.15 21:30   0   86.1    -14.2   -16
NLAD    27.2.15 21:45   0   86.1    -14.3   -16.1
NLAD    27.2.15 22:00   0   86.6    -14.4   -16.2
NLAD    27.2.15 22:15   0   86.6    -14.4   -16.2
NLAD    27.2.15 22:30   0   86.6    -14.4   -16.2
NLAD    27.2.15 22:45   0   86.8    -14.5   -16.2
NLAD    27.2.15 23:00   0   87  -14.6   -16.3
NLAD    27.2.15 23:15   0   87.3    -14.5   -16.2
NLAD    27.2.15 23:30   0   87.1    -14.4   -16.1
NLAD    27.2.15 23:45   0   87.1    -14.4   -16.1
NLAD    28.2.15 0:00    0   86.2    -14.3   -16.2
NLAD    28.2.15 0:15    0   86.1    -14.3   -16.2
NLAD    28.2.15 0:30    0   86.9    -14.4   -16.1
NLAD    28.2.15 0:45    0   87.3    -14.5   -16.2
NLAD    28.2.15 1:00    0   87.2    -14.6   -16.2
NLAD    28.2.15 1:15    0   87.1    -14.5   -16.2
NLAD    28.2.15 1:30    0   87.3    -14.4   -16.1
NLAD    28.2.15 1:45    0   86.6    -14.6   -16.4
NLAD    28.2.15 2:00    0   86.6    -14.6   -16.4
NLAD    28.2.15 2:15    0   86.6    -14.7   -16.5
NLAD    28.2.15 2:30    0   86.4    -14.8   -16.6
NLAD    28.2.15 2:45    0   86.1    -14.7   -16.5
NLAD    28.2.15 3:00    0   86.5    -14.6   -16.4
NLAD    28.2.15 3:15    0   86.6    -14.6   -16.4
NLAD    28.2.15 3:30    0   86.6    -14.7   -16.4
NLAD    28.2.15 3:45    0   86.6    -14.6   -16.4
NLAD    28.2.15 4:00    0   86.6    -14.6   -16.4
NLAD    28.2.15 4:15    0   86.6    -14.6   -16.3
NLAD    28.2.15 4:30    0   86.9    -14.4   -16.1
NLAD    28.2.15 4:45    0   87.1    -14.3   -16
NLAD    28.2.15 5:00    0   87.3    -14.3   -15.9
NLAD    28.2.15 5:15    0   87.4    -14.3   -16
NLAD    28.2.15 5:30    0   87.4    -14.3   -16
NLAD    28.2.15 5:45    0   87.3    -14.3   -16
NLAD    28.2.15 6:00    0   87.6    -14.4   -16.1
NLAD    28.2.15 6:15    0   87.3    -14.5   -16.2
NLAD    28.2.15 6:30    0   87.2    -14.5   -16.2
NLAD    28.2.15 6:45    0   86.9    -14.5   -16.2
NLAD    28.2.15 7:00    0   87.3    -14.4   -16.1
NLAD    28.2.15 7:15    0   87.1    -14.4   -16.1
NLAD    28.2.15 7:30    0   87.3    -14.4   -16.1
NLAD    28.2.15 7:45    0   87.3    -14.4   -16.1
NLAD    28.2.15 8:00    0   87.3    -14.4   -16.1
NLAD    28.2.15 8:15    0   87.3    -14.4   -16.1
NLAD    28.2.15 8:30    9   87  -14.6   -16.3
NLAD    28.2.15 8:45    27  87.2    -14.5   -16.2
NLAD    28.2.15 9:00    38  86.9    -14.1   -15.8
NLAD    28.2.15 9:15    50  86.4    -13.9   -15.7
NLAD    28.2.15 9:30    76  85.5    -13.8   -15.8
NLAD    28.2.15 9:45    80  84.9    -13.6   -15.6
NLAD    28.2.15 10:00   91  84  -13.4   -15.5
NLAD    28.2.15 10:15   100 83.2    -13.1   -15.4
NLAD    28.2.15 10:30   111 81.9    -13 -15.4
NLAD    28.2.15 10:45   166 81  -12.6   -15.2
NLAD    28.2.15 11:00   194 79.1    -12.1   -15
NLAD    28.2.15 11:15   220 76.3    -12 -15.3
NLAD    28.2.15 11:30   298 73.7    -11.7   -15.5
NLAD    28.2.15 11:45   423 70.3    -11.3   -15.6
NLAD    28.2.15 12:00   352 66.4    -10.8   -15.8
NLAD    28.2.15 12:15   545 61.9    -10.2   -16.1
NLAD    28.2.15 12:30   299 58.8    -10.6   -17.1
NLAD    28.2.15 12:45   265 60.4    -11.3   -17.5
NLAD    28.2.15 13:00   553 63.2    -10.8   -16.4
NLAD    28.2.15 13:15   750 59.1    -9.9    -16.4
NLAD    28.2.15 13:30   721 51.9    -8.9    -17
NLAD    28.2.15 13:45   797 48  -8.9    -18
NLAD    28.2.15 14:00   714 48.4    -8.8    -17.8
NLAD    28.2.15 14:15   780 48.4    -9  -18
NLAD    28.2.15 14:30   786 48.4    -9.2    -18.2
NLAD    28.2.15 14:45   652 47.8    -8.8    -18
NLAD    28.2.15 15:00   843 47.6    -8.5    -17.7
NLAD    28.2.15 15:15   753 45  -8.2    -18.1
NLAD    28.2.15 15:30   418 47.3    -8.9    -18.1
NLAD    28.2.15 15:45   585 48  -8.9    -18
NLAD    28.2.15 16:00   404 46.7    -8.7    -18.1
NLAD    28.2.15 16:15   246 50.2    -10 -18.5
NLAD    28.2.15 16:30   257 56.2    -10.5   -17.5
NLAD    28.2.15 16:45   253 57.7    -10.8   -17.5
NLAD    28.2.15 17:00   205 59.3    -10.8   -17.2
NLAD    28.2.15 17:15   176 60.1    -11.2   -17.4
NLAD    28.2.15 17:30   132 62.1    -11.5   -17.3
NLAD    28.2.15 17:45   121 63.2    -11.7   -17.3
NLAD    28.2.15 18:00   85  64.5    -11.9   -17.3
NLAD    28.2.15 18:15   54  65.8    -12.1   -17.2
NLAD    28.2.15 18:30   34  66.7    -12.3   -17.2
NLAD    28.2.15 18:45   17  68.4    -12.6   -17.1
NLAD    28.2.15 19:00   0   69.6    -12.7   -17.1
NLAD    28.2.15 19:15   0   70.5    -12.9   -17.2
NLAD    28.2.15 19:30   0   71.2    -13.1   -17.2
NLAD    28.2.15 19:45   0   72.1    -13.1   -17.1
NLAD    28.2.15 20:00   0   73.5    -13.2   -16.9
NLAD    28.2.15 20:15   0   74.3    -13.3   -16.9
NLAD    28.2.15 20:30   0   74.2    -13.4   -17
NLAD    28.2.15 20:45   0   74.3    -13.4   -17
NLAD    28.2.15 21:00   0   74.6    -13.4   -16.9
NLAD    28.2.15 21:15   0   74.5    -13.4   -17
NLAD    28.2.15 21:30   0   74.5    -13.4   -16.9
NLAD    28.2.15 21:45   0   74.8    -13.4   -16.9
NLAD    28.2.15 22:00   0   75.6    -13.4   -16.8
NLAD    28.2.15 22:15   0   76.2    -13.4   -16.7
NLAD    28.2.15 22:30   0   76.3    -13.4   -16.7
NLAD    28.2.15 22:45   0   76.4    -13.4   -16.7
NLAD    28.2.15 23:00   0   76.6    -13.4   -16.7
NLAD    28.2.15 23:15   0   76.8    -13.5   -16.7
NLAD    28.2.15 23:30   0   77  -13.5   -16.7
NLAD    28.2.15 23:45   0   77  -13.5   -16.7
NLAD    1.3.15 0:00 0   77.4    -13.5   -16.6
NLAD    1.3.15 0:15 0   78.1    -13.5   -16.5
NLAD    1.3.15 0:30 0   79  -13.5   -16.4
NLAD    1.3.15 0:45 0   80  -13.6   -16.3
NLAD    1.3.15 1:00 0   81.9    -13.4   -15.9
NLAD    1.3.15 1:15 0   83.8    -13.2   -15.4
NLAD    1.3.15 1:30 0   84  -13.2   -15.4
NLAD    1.3.15 1:45 0   82.8    -13.2   -15.5
NLAD    1.3.15 2:00 0   81.7    -13.1   -15.6
NLAD    1.3.15 2:15 0   81.3    -13.1   -15.6
NLAD    1.3.15 2:30 0   81.4    -13.1   -15.6
NLAD    1.3.15 2:45 0   82.8    -13.2   -15.5
NLAD    1.3.15 3:00 0   84.6    -13.2   -15.2
NLAD    1.3.15 3:15 0   85.4    -13 -15
NLAD    1.3.15 3:30 0   85.5    -12.9   -14.9
NLAD    1.3.15 3:45 0   85.2    -13.1   -15.1
NLAD    1.3.15 4:00 0   85.2    -13 -15
NLAD    1.3.15 4:15 0   86.1    -12.9   -14.7
NLAD    1.3.15 4:30 0   86.6    -12.7   -14.5
NLAD    1.3.15 4:45 0   86.8    -12.7   -14.4
NLAD    1.3.15 5:00 0   87  -12.6   -14.3
NLAD    1.3.15 5:15 0   87.4    -12.8   -14.5
NLAD    1.3.15 5:30 0   87.9    -12.8   -14.4
NLAD    1.3.15 5:45 0   88.2    -12.6   -14.1
NLAD    1.3.15 6:00 0   88.1    -12.4   -14
NLAD    1.3.15 6:15 0   87.9    -12.3   -13.9
NLAD    1.3.15 6:30 0   87.7    -12.3   -14
NLAD    1.3.15 6:45 0   88  -12.6   -14.2
NLAD    1.3.15 7:00 0   88.8    -12.4   -13.9
NLAD    1.3.15 7:15 0   89.8    -12.3   -13.6
NLAD    1.3.15 7:30 0   90.5    -12.2   -13.4
NLAD    1.3.15 7:45 0   90.3    -12.3   -13.6
NLAD    1.3.15 8:00 0   89.4    -12.2   -13.6
NLAD    1.3.15 8:15 0   87.7    -12.4   -14
NLAD    1.3.15 8:30 0   86.9    -12.4   -14.1
NLAD    1.3.15 8:45 16  85.4    -12.4   -14.4
NLAD    1.3.15 9:00 35  84  -12.4   -14.5
NLAD    1.3.15 9:15 53  83.8    -12.6   -14.7
NLAD    1.3.15 9:30 76  84.2    -12.6   -14.7
NLAD    1.3.15 9:45 104 83  -12.3   -14.6
NLAD    1.3.15 10:00    123 81.1    -12.1   -14.6
NLAD    1.3.15 10:15    136 76.9    -11.7   -14.9
NLAD    1.3.15 10:30    181 71.8    -11.1   -15.1
NLAD    1.3.15 10:45    203 69.6    -10.7   -15.2
NLAD    1.3.15 11:00    257 66.6    -10.4   -15.4
NLAD    1.3.15 11:15    385 61.2    -9.8    -15.9
NLAD    1.3.15 11:30    523 54.1    -8.5    -16.1
NLAD    1.3.15 11:45    734 50.4    -8.2    -16.8
NLAD    1.3.15 12:00    139 51.8    -9.2    -17.3
NLAD    1.3.15 12:15    342 60.7    -9.8    -16
NLAD    1.3.15 12:30    484 58.8    -9.9    -16.4
NLAD    1.3.15 12:45    278 58.5    -9.6    -16.2
NLAD    1.3.15 13:00    554 58.6    -8.9    -15.6
NLAD    1.3.15 13:15    827 55.5    -7.9    -15.3
NLAD    1.3.15 13:30    249 53.7    -7.9    -15.7
NLAD    1.3.15 13:45    255 55.9    -9.2    -16.4
NLAD    1.3.15 14:00    348 58.5    -9.3    -15.9
NLAD    1.3.15 14:15    1006    53.5    -7.7    -15.6
NLAD    1.3.15 14:30    372 48  -7.7    -16.9
NLAD    1.3.15 14:45    317 50.4    -8.7    -17.2
NLAD    1.3.15 15:00    359 51.3    -8.1    -16.4
NLAD    1.3.15 15:15    728 50.2    -8.2    -16.8
NLAD    1.3.15 15:30    520 51.3    -8.8    -17.1
NLAD    1.3.15 15:45    270 49  -8.4    -17.3
NLAD    1.3.15 16:00    591 49.2    -8  -16.8
NLAD    1.3.15 16:15    611 46  -8  -17.7
NLAD    1.3.15 16:30    449 50.6    -8.7    -17.1
NLAD    1.3.15 16:45    401 52.2    -8.9    -17
NLAD    1.3.15 17:00    230 53.8    -9.8    -17.5
NLAD    1.3.15 17:15    124 57.9    -10.2   -16.9
NLAD    1.3.15 17:30    157 59.2    -10.4   -16.8
NLAD    1.3.15 17:45    115 61.9    -11.1   -16.9
NLAD    1.3.15 18:00    86  64.7    -11.4   -16.7
NLAD    1.3.15 18:15    70  68  -11.6   -16.3
NLAD    1.3.15 18:30    48  70  -12.1   -16.4
NLAD    1.3.15 18:45    26  73.4    -12.6   -16.3
NLAD    1.3.15 19:00    16  76.3    -12.9   -16.2
NLAD    1.3.15 19:15    0   78.5    -13.2   -16.2
NLAD    1.3.15 19:30    0   80.1    -13.5   -16.2
NLAD    1.3.15 19:45    0   81.8    -13.7   -16.2
NLAD    1.3.15 20:00    0   82.8    -13.7   -16
NLAD    1.3.15 20:15    0   83.7    -13.8   -16
NLAD    1.3.15 20:30    0   84.3    -13.6   -15.7
NLAD    1.3.15 20:45    0   83.9    -13.4   -15.5
NLAD    1.3.15 21:00    0   82.7    -13.3   -15.7
NLAD    1.3.15 21:15    0   81.6    -13.4   -15.9
NLAD    1.3.15 21:30    0   82.4    -13.3   -15.6
NLAD    1.3.15 21:45    0   84  -13.4   -15.5
NLAD    1.3.15 22:00    0   84.4    -13.3   -15.4
NLAD    1.3.15 22:15    0   84  -13.3   -15.4
NLAD    1.3.15 22:30    0   83  -13.3   -15.6
NLAD    1.3.15 22:45    0   81.9    -13.3   -15.8
NLAD    1.3.15 23:00    0   82  -13.4   -15.8
NLAD    1.3.15 23:15    0   83.3    -13.2   -15.5
NLAD    1.3.15 23:30    0   84.4    -13.1   -15.2
NLAD    1.3.15 23:45    0   85.9    -13 -14.9}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and use `dput` to attach data. At the moment, it is unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied the data into a file and used `read.table`, therefore I had to adjust the column names.

```
tmp <- read.table("c:/users/a904599/desktop/file.txt", skip = 1)

colnames(tmp) <- c("Loc", "Date", "Time", "PAR", "HMD", "TMP", "DEW")
```

After that, I created a DateTime column and converted to POSIX.

```
tmp$DateTime <- with(tmp, paste(Date, Time))

tmp$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(tmp$DateTime, format = "%d.%m.%y %H:%M")
```

Now `melt` and `ggplot`should yield what you want.

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)

tmp2 <- melt(tmp, id.vars = c("Loc", "DateTime"),
                  measure.vars = c("PAR", "HMD", "TMP", "DEW"),
                  variable.name = "Parameter",
                  value.name = "Value")

ggplot(tmp2, aes(DateTime, Value, col = Loc)) +
    facet_wrap(~Parameter, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the following I am assuming your data is in a data frame called `df`.

First of all you would need to convert your time column into a POSIX object.

There are several ways to do it, for instance using `as.POSIXct`.
Note that, as your date format is non-standard you need to specify the `format` parameter.

```
df$time <- as.POSIXct(df$time, format="%d.%m.%y %T")
```

Now you can split the data by location, so that it will create a list with one element per location

```
df.split <- split(df, df$location)
```

You can now access each element using its index (e.g. `df.split[[2]]` to get the second element) or alternatively using its name (e.g. `df.split$NLAD`).

For each element you can plot the temperature simply using the plot function:

```
plot(TMP~time, df.split[[1]], t="o", pch=20)
```

If you want to plot everything on the same plot you can do:

```
# Create an empty plot with appropriate limits
# We hide the x axis with xaxt="n" because otherwise dates 
# are not printed nicely
plot(0, t="n", xlab="Time", ylab="Temperature", 
     xlim=c(min(df$time), max(df$time)), ylim=c(-15, 25),
     las=1, xaxt="n")

# Use sapply to go through each element of the list (location)
# and points to add to the graph
sapply(df.split, function(x){points(x$time, x$TMP, t="o", pch=20, cex=0.7)})

# Add a nice x axis
ticks <- seq(min(df$time), max(df$time), 3600*6) # Ticks every 6 hours
axis(1, at=ticks, labels = strftime(ticks, "%d/%m %H:%M"))
```

---

**Note**: I saved your data in a csv file and imported it using

```
df <- read.csv("tempdata.csv")
```

Be sure to put the output of `dput` for yout next question, it makes things much more easier for those who answer (and be sure to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)).